# BASH multiple variable in CASE statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, case

I have 2 separate case statements

one for AZURE cidr block

```
 net_prefix=${VNET_CIDR_BLOCK#*/}
    
    case "$net_prefix" in
    
    0) azure_wildcard_mask=255.255.255.255
     ;;
    
    esac
```

and second for AWS Cidr

```
aws_net_prefix=${AWS_VPC_CIDR_BLOCK#*/}

case "$aws_net_prefix" in

0) aws_wildcard_mask=255.255.255.255
 ;;
  esac
```

is it possible somehow to combine above 2 CASE into one. for example

```
 A=$1
    
    B=$2
    
    net_prefix=${A#*/}
    
    aws_prefix=${B#*/}
    
    case "$net_prefix" OR "$aws_prefix" in
    
    0) aws_wildcard_mask=255.255.255.255
       azure_wildcard_mask=255.255.255.255
     ;;
```

i need both aws_wildcard and azure_wildcard_mask variables

i tried this one

```
if [ "$azure_prefix" == "19" ] || [ "$aws_prefix" == "19" ]

then
  azure_wildcard="255.255.255.255"
  aws_wildcard="255.255.255.255"

elif [ "$azure_prefix" == "20" ] || [ "$aws_prefix" == "20" ]

then
  azure_wildcard="127.255.255.255"
  aws_wildcard="127.255.255.255"
fi

echo $azure_wildcard
echo $aws_wildcard
```

and executed it:

```
./2.sh 10.10.0.0/19 20.20.20.0/20
```

getting same output

> 255.255.255.255
>
> 255.255.255.255

Comment: yes, but changing to `if [ A = x ] || [ B = y ]]` or `if [[ A =~ x || B =~ y ]]` will be simpler and probably more efficient

Comment: thanks, please see updated question

Comment: Your original question wasn't clear. The example makes it more obvious what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you call a prefix is not a prefix but a bit length.

Comment: thanks for corrections

Comment: @ceving rfc4632 uses the terminology quite loosely  ("the prefix 172.16.0.0/16", "/8 prefixes", a /21 prefix", etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract the case into a function:

```
A=$1
B=$2

getmask(){
    case "$1" in
        19) echo 255.255.255.255 ;;
        20) echo 127.255.255.255 ;;
    esac
}

azure_wildcard_mask=$(getmask ${A#*/})
aws_wildcard_mask=$(getmask ${B#*/})
```

Answer (score 0):

The string after `case` can be an arbitrary expression. Perhaps something like this?

```
case $aws_prefix::$net_prefix in
    0::* | *::0 )
        aws_wildcard_mask=255.255.255.255
        azure_wildcard_mask=255.255.255.255 ;;
esac
```